# how to print both side of paper with perfect positioning?

Tags: print-design, print-production, digital-printing

I know that all home printers can't do double side print with perfect accuracy, but is there any other printer you can buy that is specialized on this ? thanks!

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/119371/63979) please don't make multiple posts.

Answer (score 0):

Pen plotters with moving print head and non-moving paper can do it. You must flip and place the sheet manually between the runs. If the paper is held with electric field in place, you can expect good results.